# nodejs web scraping and callback issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, cheerio

I am trying to scrape a website for some content, it all works good but then the scraped text is available for me just in console however I want to print this scraped data on my browser. I think I am doing something wrong with the way I am handling callbacks. Can anyone please help?

My code is below:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    
      //All the web scraping magic will happen here
    var url = 'https://www.mywebsite.com/path/to/abc';
  var allText;
  var getTheText = function() {
          request(url, function getText(error, response, html){

        // First we'll check to make sure no errors occurred when making the request

        if(!error){
            // Next, we'll utilize the cheerio library on the returned html which will essentially give us jQuery functionality

            var $ = cheerio.load(html);

            // Finally, we'll define the variables we're going to capture
            
          var allText = $('body').children().find('p').text()

                console.log('allText');
                console.log(allText);
            return allText; 
        }
        else {
        }

        //return result;
    });   
          console.log(allText);
   
  }

getTheText();
  console.log('gettheText is ' + getTheText());
  res.send(allText);
})
```

Comment: Just a tip, don't process cheerio wile processing request. Push it into background job using redis or kue. Once you are done with scraping push the results to websocket or send an event over ws to fetch results

Answer (score 0):

Send response from callback function where data is available.
Please see code below:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {

  //All the web scraping magic will happen here
  var url = 'https://www.mywebsite.com/path/to/abc';
  var allText;
  var getTheText = function() {
    request(url, function getText(error, response, html) {

      // First we'll check to make sure no errors occurred when making the request

      if (!error) {
        // Next, we'll utilize the cheerio library on the returned html which will essentially give us jQuery functionality

        var $ = cheerio.load(html);

        // Finally, we'll define the variables we're going to capture

        var allText = $('body')
          .children()
          .find('p')
          .text()

        console.log('allText');
        console.log(allText);
        // return allText;
        res.send(allText); // Send response from here
      } else {}

      //return result;
    });
    console.log(allText);

  }

  getTheText();
  console.log('gettheText is ' + getTheText());
  // res.send(allText); // Remove this line
})
```